Proving inequality that arises in projected gradient descent
I am reading a paper in which the author uses projected gradient descent to produce iterates of the form:
$$\pi_{t + 1} = \underset{\pi \in \Pi}{\arg \max}\left\{ \left \langle \pi, Q \right \rangle - \frac{1}{2 \eta} \left \lVert \pi - \pi_t \right \rVert_2^2 \right\}$$
where $\Pi$ is a set of finite-dimensional vectors. The author then claims for all $\pi' \in \Pi$ it holds that
$$\left \langle \pi' - \pi_{t + 1}, \eta Q - \pi_{t + 1} + \pi_t \right \rangle \leq 0$$
By optimality of $\pi_{t + 1}$ I can deduce
$$\left \langle \pi_{t + 1}, Q \right \rangle - \frac{1}{2 \eta} \left \lVert \pi_{t + 1} - \pi_t \right \rVert_2^2 \geq \left \langle \pi', Q \right \rangle - \frac{1}{2 \eta} \left \lVert \pi' - \pi_t \right \rVert_2^2$$
and therefore
$$\left \langle \pi' - \pi_{t + 1}, \eta Q \right \rangle \leq \frac{1}{2} \left \lVert \pi' - \pi_t \right \rVert_2^2 - \frac{1}{2} \left \lVert \pi_{t + 1} - \pi_t \right \rVert_2^2$$
but it remains for me to show
$$\frac{1}{2} \left \lVert \pi' - \pi_t \right \rVert_2^2 - \frac{1}{2} \left \lVert \pi_{t + 1} - \pi_t \right \rVert_2^2 \leq \left\langle \pi' - \pi_{t + 1}, \pi_{t + 1} - \pi_t \right\rangle$$
Any help would be appreciated!
EDIT: Note the update can also be written
$$\pi_{t + 1} = \mathtt{Proj}_{\Pi} \Big \{ \pi_t + \eta Q \Big \}$$

The inequality you’re asking for help proving is false if $\pi’ = \pi_t$

Hm indeed it is. I don't think that's enough to disprove the author's claim, though. I am still looking to prove $$\left \langle \pi' - \pi_{t + 1}, \eta Q - \pi_{t + 1} + \pi_t \right \rangle \leq 0$$

Isn’t that statement also false if $\pi’ = \eta Q + \pi_t$, unless $\pi_{t+1} = \eta Q + \pi_t$, in which case the inequality is trivially true as it is always equal to $0$?

If we can choose $\pi' = \eta Q + \pi_t$ then $\eta Q + \pi_t \in \Pi$ and necessarily $\pi_{t + 1} = \eta Q + \pi_t$.

I'm fairly convinced this must be wrong unless you have some further conditions on $\Pi$. Consider the $1D$ case for $\Pi = [-1, 1]$ with $Q = \eta = 1$ and set $\pi_0 = 0$. Then $\pi_1 = \frac{1}{2}$. Then the inequality becomes $\frac{1}{2}(\pi' - \frac{1}{2}) \leq 0$, which is false for e.g. $\pi' = 1$.

You're right there's a further condition on $\Pi$ (see my answer below). Your example is flawed though; you should get $\pi_{1} = 1$.

There's a further condition that $\Pi$ is convex, which is key. It is then a direct application of Theorem 2.1 here.
